# Finding id of elements

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have this bit of html.
(Link at bottom)

Its output of php code for status updates, it has view comments and post comment link, the post comment link uses jquery to add a textarea and submit button below that status update. and the view comments shows the comments to that status update below that status update.

So i use php looping so there will be obviously more than 1 status updates at most times(depends on how much friends users have) so i cant have an element like 'textelement', i will need to have elements like 'textelement1' and 'textelement2'
So i used php to add the id of the status update in the end of the links like _id so the element id  becomes view_comments_1.

So i want to use jquery to find out which element has been clicked so that i can add a text box and show comments below the right status update instead of showing it below all status updates.

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapbg">

    <span class="corners-top"><span></span></span>
    <div id="content"><br/>
        Whats new?
        <hr class='hr1'>

        <div class='stbody' id='stbody'>

            <div class='stimg'>
                <img src='uploads/profile_pics_small/Anonymous_Blueprint_Wallpaper_by_co.jpg' /></img>
            </div>
            <div class='sttext'>
                Welcome yoall!!
                <div class='sttime'>By LUcase</div>
                <br><br>

                <a href=''>0 Likes</a> <a href=''>1 Dislikes</a>
            </div>
            <a href=''>unDislike</a> <a id='comment_now_1' href=''>Comment</a> <a id='view_comments1' data-id-1 = '1' href=''>View comments</a> <div id='emptydiv1'> </div></div>
        <div class='stbody' id='stbody'>

            <div class='stimg'>

                <img src='uploads/profile_pics_small/wood_texture_by_pabloalvin-d1igijr.jpg' /></img>
            </div>
            <div class='sttext'>
                hi
                <div class='sttime'>By nicknick</div>
                <br><br>
                <a href=''>0 Likes</a> <a href=''>0 Dislikes</a>
            </div>
            <a href=''>Like</a> <a href=''>DisLike</a> <a id='comment_now_4' href=''>Comment</a> <a id='view_comments4' data-id-4 = '4' href=''>View comments</a> <div id='emptydiv4'> </div></div></div>

    <span class="corners-bottom"><span></span></span>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
    //Gotta find out which status update we are dealing with!
    jQuery("document").ready(function(){
        jQuery(".likebtn").click(function(e) {
            var id=jQuery(this).attr("data-id");
            jQuery.post('like.php', {'id': id}, function(data) {
                alert("Your like.php has been called");
            }, "json");
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        jQuery(".dislikebtn").click(function(e) {
        });

//gotta figure out which status update we are dealing with!
//attache the click event to the anchor tag
        $("#comment_now").live("click",function(e){
            //prevent the default behaviour of following the link
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#comment_now").remove();
            //find the textarea element, and after it, put an input tag
            $(".sttext").after('<textarea id="comment_text" name="comment"></textarea> <br> <button id = "post_button" class="action greenbtn"><span class="label">Comment</span></button> <a id="cancel_comment" href="">Cancel</a> <br id="com_spacing">');
        });



//gotta figure out which status update we are dealing with!
        $("#cancel_comment").live("click",function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#comment_text").remove();
            $("#cancel_comment").remove();
            $("#post_button").remove();
            $("#com_spacing").remove();
            $("#view_comments").before('<a href="" id="comment_now">Comment</a> ');
        });

        $("#view_comments").live("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var id=jQuery(this).attr("data-id");
            $.ajax({

                url: 'query_comments.php?status_id='+id,
                beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                    xhr.overrideMimeType( 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8' );
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    $('#emptydiv').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Please help me out :)

Comment: you can post the relevant code here

Comment: I did it for you, do it yourself next time please.

Comment: Your HTML has duplicate IDs, that's invalid and will cause problems with JavaScript and jQuery. Only one of the same ID can exist on a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a class to to action buttons and pass the comment id as `data` attribute like so:

`<a class="commentBtn" href='' data-commentid="1">Comment</a>`

and than you can read out the id easily with jquery:

`$(".commentBtn").live("click",function(e){
   var id = $(this).data('commentid');
   e.preventDefault();
   // do something with id…
});`

Comment: i pressed the green tick button if thats what your talking about :)

Answer (score 4):

You know that html forms can send arrays, right?

```
<input type="text" name="textelement[]" value="First Element" /><br/>
<input type="text" name="textelement[]" value="Second Element" /><br/>
```

PHP Code:

```
foreach($_POST['textelement'] as $somethingSomething){
    echo $somethingSomething, "\n";
}
```

Prints out:

```
 First Element
 Second Element
```

Comment: Sorry but how is this related to my question?

Comment: It is supposed to help you find an alternative way of implementation.